# Can parent node positions be moved via child node positions in SceneKit (swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, scenekit

I am currently trying to get to grips with SceneKit using Apple's Swift language, it seems nice and straight forward but I was wondering if anyone has been able to move an entire nodes position by changing a child nodes position?

I mean, naturally moving the parent would move the child but I am using snap points in models to position objects correctly and the snap points are children of the overall object node.

For example, I want to snap object A's child node to object B's child node (overall moving object B to the correct offset). I do currently have this implemented, the positions are working correctly, all the correct values are in place however the parent model isn't moving on demand. Is this actually possible or am I following a wrong path?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

that's definitely possible, but you will have to write your own utils.

If `T` is the transform (translation) that allows you to position your child nodes correctly, you can use `[nodeBChildNode convertTransform:T toNode:nodeB]` to convert that transform and then apply it on `nodeB`.

Comment: I can't seem to get anything to transform at all, very strange :/ I can move it with defined offsets but that's no use :( I will keep trying and report back if I manage it!